# Check if expression matches a regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to validate the following expressions :

1. "CODE1:123/CODE2:3467/CODE1:7686"
2. "CODE1:9090"
3. "CODE2:078/CODE1:7788/CODE1:333"
4. "CODE2:77"

In my case, the patterns 'CODE1:xx' or 'CODE2:xx' are given in any different orders.
I can sort the patterns to make them like 'CODE1:XX/CODE1:YY/CODE2:ZZ'
and check if matches something like

> r'[CODE1:\d+]*[CODE2:\d+]*'

Could we make it shorter : is it possible to solve this with one regex matcher ?
Thanks

Comment: The posted regex: `r'[CODE1:\d+]*[CODE2:\d+]*'` should not work because the first and third examples show that code1 can come after code2 as well. I suggest that before getting into the smaller details of the regex and trying to improve it, update the question to explain what is it that we're trying to achieve: it could be that regex is not the right tool for the job!

Comment: The pattern that you tried works different than matching the word CODE1: followed by 1 or more digits as it is inside a character class. It is the same as `[:+C\dEDO]*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will provide a match for all 4 cases:
`CODE[12]:\d+(?:/CODE[12]:\d+)*`

See here: https://regex101.com/r/wn30a5/1

It will match `CODE` followed by either `1` or `2` and then a colon `:` with digits; and optionally followed by a slash `/` and that pattern again, any number of times. So a trailing slash won't be permitted and it can appear as a single code too; and in any order; so it doesn't need to be sorted first.

Comment: You can shorten it to `CODE[12]:\d+(?:/CODE[12]:\d+)*` https://regex101.com/r/wn30a5/1

Answer (score 1):

`CODE` is static but after it the digit is dynamic, to make it shorter just use `CODE\d:\d+`

if you want to match only two digit after `:` use `CODE\d:\d{2}`